# Standard error of an estimate from a non-probability sample?

Tags: sampling, inference, resampling

Assume one tries to estimate the mean price of an item by employing a non-probability sample due to the lack of a survey frame of the universe of all items. How would I go about calculating the standard error of the mean? Now, if I add that the non-probability sample is also a representative sample, would this make any difference?

I search for similar posts, but none of them really touch on this subject. My main goal is to construct confidence intervals for my estimate. Is bootstrapping a good alternative here? (as suggested in p2 of [this](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/bdr/IAUL/Course1Notes6.pdf) note)

Comment: In what sense would the sample be representative? You usually cannot just look at a sample and determine if it is representative, its a function of the data collection process.

Comment: @Bey Youre right, I can't know. But let's assume I do know that it's a representative sample because somehow I sampled the same elements as a SRS would. Any thoughts on my question now that I cleared this up?

Comment: Well, if its equivalent to SRS, then treat it as such. No issue there. Most of the challenge with non-random sampling is getting to the state you are assuming is true.

Comment: If this is the case then, would there be any added benefit of doing a bootstrap, to estimate the CI's?

Comment: Depends: do you know the underlying distributional form (e.g., normal) or can you invoke CLT? A boostrap study will never hurt an analysis, as it can at least provide a baseline against which to compare other methods.

Comment: I don't know the underlying distributional form of the population, but my suspiscion is that it's log-normal. In terms of invoking the CLT, I have a sample size of over 500 observations.

Comment: Bootstrap should be just fine.

Comment: No proper sample can be truly representative of a population in the sense of closely reproducing *all* its properties. Therefore bootstrapping will not detect a failure of representativeness--it is no panacea. The *only* way to obtain legitimate confidence intervals for such samples is through explicit probability models.  Without such a model you have nothing to go on.

Comment: I agree with @whuber.  Moreover, the notion  that a probability sample requires a frame  that lists all population elements  is false. The most common such design is multi-stage sampling, but there are others. For many examples see WE Deming, Sample Design in Business Research, Wiley, 1960, or Kish, 1965, Survey Sampling,.